# How to check if a certain amount of time has passed in Momentjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am creating a project in NodeJS and i want to be able to check if a certain amount of time (say 1 hour) has passed after creating an object. I am using MomentJS.

Assume `moment(book.createdAt).fromNow()` returns say *2 hours ago*. I want to have an if condition which checks if `moment(book.createdAt).fromNow()` is LESS THAN 1 HOUR AGO.

Can someone please tell how this logic can be implemented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDITING IN 2023:**

The question is asking specifically about Moment.js BUT... if you're reading this in 2023 and beyond, [per Moment.js website](https://momentjs.com/), you should know that:

> Considering using Moment in your project?
> There may be better modern alternatives.
> For more details and recommendations,
> please see Project Status in the docs.

I won't get into details because the official documentation does it way better than I could, so [have a look](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) at what the Moment.js team has to say about it.

That being said...

---

Using moment, you can do this:

```
if(moment(yourDate).isAfter(moment().subtract(1, 'hours'))){
    ...
};
```

In that case, you are testing if `yourDate` is less than one hour ago compared to now.

You could also use JavaScript without any other external library:

```
const hour = 60 * 60 * 1000; //(60seconds * 60minutes * 1000ms, to get the milliseconds)
const hourAgo = Date.now() - hour;

if(yourDate > anHourAgo) { 
    // yourDate is less than an hour ago
}
```